Why is it possible to generate a random real from the uniform distribution, but not a random rational from an equivalent distribution??
Why is it possible to generate a random real from the uniform distribution, but not a random rational or algebraic number from a distribution with similar properties?

Do you understand why we can't uniformly sample $\Bbb Z$? Can you see why the same logic applies to $\Bbb Q$, or $\Bbb Q\cap[0,,1)$ for that matter?

There is no uniform distribution on a countably infinite set since for mutually exclusive events you have $P\left(\bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^\infty E_i\right) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty P(E_i)$: if all the $P(E_i)$ were equal, you would either get a total probability of $0$ or get $\infty$ when it should be $1$.

I do understand, but my question is about the reals. Why is it possible in the reals?

It's not unless you're referring to Bayesian improper priors. If you're not, then you have to specify a finite range for your distribution.

Let's assume $A$ is some subset of the real interval $[0,1]$. We have 3 cases:

$A$ is finite, $|A| =n$. Then we can have a uniform probability for any $x\in A$: $P(x)=1/n$. In this way, $P(X \in A) = \sum_{x\in A} P(x) = 1$ and we are fine.

$A$ is countably infinite. Then either $P(x)=0$ or $P(x)=\epsilon >0$. But in the first case $P(X \in A) = \sum_{x\in A} P(x) = 0$ (no good) and in the second case  $\sum_{x\in A} P(x) = \infty$ . So in neither case we can build a uniform probability.

$A$ is infinite not countable. In this case we might have $P(x)=0$ but still $P(X \in A)=1$ because the total event cannot be descomposed as a countable union, which would result in countable sum of zero probabilities. This is the case of the $A=[0,1]$ using the standard measure.


So, the rationals are "too many" (to be assigned a positive probability) and "too few" (to be assigned a zero probability).
More in detail: see Countable vs. Uncountable Probability or Probability measure on the Rationals. density function, and integration?  or Uniform measure on the rationals between 0 and 1
See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4945371/312 ("there's no such thing as choosing a random element of a countably infinite set uniformly at random")
